# cannot compile flutter app - Kotlin related error

Tags: kotlin, flutter, compilation

I've been trying to publish my app, but the appbundle is failing:

the command I'm using is:

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Here is my error code

```
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

There maybe a problem with my Gradle.build file. So Here it is - but it came from the standard file produced with any new flutter project. I just followed the instructions in adding my keys etc.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {


    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.domain.appname"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias "key"
            keyPassword "password"
            storeFile file("/Users/mypath/appKeys/appDir/key.jks")
            storePassword "password"
        }
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

also, my build.gradle file is here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: add your root gradle

Comment: hello. You mean my build.gradle file? I've added that. I do apologise if that's not what you are referring to. I am really new to Gradle

Comment: there are two gradle files one at root/project  and one on app level/module.need to see the root . see image for more.  https://developer.android.com/images/tools/studio/project-structure_2x.png  .seems like you dont have kotlin preinstaled.you can install via android studio plugins

Comment: Hello. I checked and it is installed. What makes you think that its not installed?

Comment: add it to your root gradle and sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your gradle you dont have kotlin installed. follow the following to add kotlin to your project,**Go to File > Settings > Plugins > Install JetBrains plugin and search “Kotlin” and install it**. When installing complete, Android Studio will restart.

then update your gradle to match this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I checked and indeed Kotlin plugin is installed. In fact, it is hard to even remove it.

Comment: Add kotlin to your gradle file..else create an empty kotlin file and android studio will handle the rest